# Oracle function to pull data from XMLTABLE

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltable

I am trying to write a function in Oracle that will allow me to specify the tag names and get a single specific value back.  So, if the snippet below is part of my XML, I want to send the path, sequence number, and specific field I want, and get the value back.

```
<variables>
<variablesList>
    <sequence>1</sequence>
    <variableType>C1SQ</variableType>
    <missingValueAction>C1ER</missingValueAction>
    <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
    <uom>KWB</uom>
    <tou>SUMMER</tou>
    <serviceQuantityToUse>C1BI</serviceQuantityToUse>
    <targetCalcLines/>
</variablesList>
<variablesList>
    <sequence>2</sequence>
    <variableType>C1SQ</variableType>
    <missingValueAction>C1ER</missingValueAction>
    <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
    <uom>KWB</uom>
    <tou>WINTER</tou>
    <serviceQuantityToUse>C1BI</serviceQuantityToUse>
    <targetCalcLines/>
</variablesList>
```

My function header is defined as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function cm_get_bo_data_TableValue (pTableTag varchar2, pFieldTag varchar2, pSequence varchar2, pBODataValue CLOB)
```

I call the function like this:

```
select BO_DATA_AREA
 , cm_get_bo_data_TableValue ('/root/variables/variablesList', 'tou', '2', BO_DATA_AREA)
from CM_CI1558A_BO_DATA_AUDIT
```

But, it only works for 'tou' because I can't seem to put a variable in the PATH.

So, if I have the following, it will return a value:

```
select TagValue into v_value
from dual, XMLTable(pTableTag PASSING XMLTYPE( to_clob('<root>') || pBODataValue || '</root>' ) 
                  COLUMNS sequence_num          VARCHAR2(10)    PATH 'sequence',
                          TagValue              VARCHAR2(10)    PATH 'tou'
    
) t
where sequence_num = pSequence;

return v_value;
```

but if I replace that 'tou' with pFieldTag, it says the SQL is wrong and tells me it was expecting a string.

```
                              TagValue              VARCHAR2(10)    PATH pFieldTag
```

I want to be able to specify each specific tag and get the value back; I need to deal with them one at a time, and want something generic that will work for more than this specific XML structure.

In other words, I want to be able to specify sequence 1 for tou and get 'SUMMER', sequence 2 for uom and get 'KWB', and sequence 1 for a completely different tag and structure and get that value too - for any of the table values that we might encounter (there are a few).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to create special function for that, since Oracle has very good function xmlquery. For example, if you want to get some value from xmltype by xquery:

xmlcast(
xmlquery(
'/root/variables/variablesList[2]/tou' -- <== your path, from your question
passing xmltype(xmldata)
returning content
)
as varchar2(100)
) res

Full example:

```
with test_table(xmldata) as (
select 
q'[
<variables>
<variablesList>
    <sequence>1</sequence>
    <variableType>C1SQ</variableType>
    <missingValueAction>C1ER</missingValueAction>
    <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
    <uom>KWB</uom>
    <tou>SUMMER</tou>
    <serviceQuantityToUse>C1BI</serviceQuantityToUse>
    <targetCalcLines/>
</variablesList>
<variablesList>
    <sequence>2</sequence>
    <variableType>C1SQ</variableType>
    <missingValueAction>C1ER</missingValueAction>
    <defaultValue>0</defaultValue>
    <uom>KWB</uom>
    <tou>WINTER</tou>
    <serviceQuantityToUse>C1BI</serviceQuantityToUse>
    <targetCalcLines/>
</variablesList>
</variables>
]'
from dual
)
select
  xmlcast(
     xmlquery(
        '&input_path[&input_sequence]/&input_tag/text()'
         passing xmltype(xmldata)
         returning content
     )
     as varchar2(100)
   ) res
from test_table
/
```

As you can see in this example I'm building a path from substitution variables as you asked for, ie "path[sequence]/tag".
So you will need to enter:

```
input_path: /variables/variablesList
input_sequence: 2
input_tag: tou
```

PS. In this example I do not add  tag, so I do not specify /root at the beginning (why do you need it? do you have not valid xml (without parent tag) as input?)

Comment: Yup, I've figured out it isn't valid xml, and doesn't have the parent tags.

Comment: No problem, you can wrap it as in your example and use xmlquery function from my answer

Comment: Is Oracle 11g an old version?  The closest I get results in ORA-32512: type 'xquery external variable' is unknown

Comment: Substitution values (&) aren't quite where I am going - I'll have the path and tags in a table, need to assemble what I'm looking for, and return the value.  I'm still trying to get the xmlquery to work, but there's a lot out there too.

Comment: First of all, yes, of course - 11g is EOL (end-of-life) already, but anyway I've just checked my code on 11.2.0.2 and it works fine: https://gist.github.com/xtender/01f0a2a93aa5c6e7acd84aa2365a8560

Comment: @thursdaysgeek "I'll have the path and tags in a table" - no problem, you can concatenate path easily - see my latest comment here: https://gist.github.com/xtender/01f0a2a93aa5c6e7acd84aa2365a8560

Comment: Thank you!  I finally figured out my issue.  When converting to use the actual xml, when I used 'passing xmltype(xmldata)' it choked, because it didn't need to be cast as xmltype.  Just using xmldata was appropriate.